# Why normalizing spin state is different? Why no need dxdydz?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, spinors

An electron in a spin state:
$$X=A\quad\begin{pmatrix} 2i\\2\end{pmatrix}\quad$$

In order to get A, I have to normalise it, my question is how should write?
Since I have to normalise why no need integral? Like
$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}X{X^*}dx dy=A^2\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}[(-2i){\bar x}+2{\bar y}][(2i){\bar x}+2{\bar y}]?$$
I don't know how to write,then I find book,it says $X{X^*}=A^2|4+4|$,so how should I write?

$X{X^*}=A^2 \quad\begin{pmatrix} 2i\\2\end{pmatrix}\quad \quad\begin{pmatrix} -2i\\2\end{pmatrix}\quad$

Or $X{X^*}=A^2[(-2i){\bar x}+2{\bar y}][(2i){\bar x}+2{\bar y}]$

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to integrate anything here. The wavefunction is represented as a two component spinor here, which represents the probability of observing a certain spin along some axis. The components of the spinor refer to how the spin of the particle is oriented, they do not represent $x$ and $y$ components of a vector. So the inner product defined for such a space is simply $|X|^{2}=X^{*}\cdot X=\sum_{i=1}^{2}X_{i}^{*}X_{i}$, which is what the book says.